# jquery scrollTop help needed

Tags: jquery, scroll

My code is:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop : $('#current').offset().top}, 300, easeInOutExpo);
```

What it does is scroll the item (#current) to the top of the window. 
I want it to scroll the item to - **100px down from top**.
How can I achieve that? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
  scrollTop: $('#current').offset().top - 100
}, 300, easeInOutExpo);
```

Gets the current top of the `#current` element and takes another 100 pixels from that value - leaving the `#current` element 100px from the top of the window